# Xmonad - How do I move mouse pointer as part of ManageHook?

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea, mouse, xmonad

Given this sample `myManageHook`. How can I call [UpdatePointer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Actions-UpdatePointer.html) after `doIgnore`? All my tries resulted in type incompatibilities.

```
myManageHook = composeAll . concat $
    [
      -- IntelliJ idea Tweaks
      -- Manage idea completion window
      , [ appName =? "sun-awt-X11-XWindowPeer" <&&> className =? "jetbrains-idea" --> doIgnore ]
      , [ (className ~=? "jetbrains-") <&&> (title ~=? "Changes in") -->  unfloat ]
    ]
    where
      unfloat = ask >>= doF . W.sink
```

My problem is that IntelliJ Idea popup window loses focus during typing if my mouse pointer is located over suggestions dropbox. That's why I'm trying to move the mouse to an upper part of the screen when this window appears.

[image]

**UPD** Found related thread with workarounds for Idea https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112015#comment=27-2362253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `liftX` to turn an `X` action into a `Query` action. You probably want to use `XMonad.Actions.Warp` instead of `X.A.UpdatePointer` instead, though; the latter looks like it might do a bit too much magic to sensibly fire during a manage hook. Anyway you should be able to try that out yourself once you see how to lift `X` actions.

So, for `banish`, you could use `liftX` like this:

```
... --> (liftX (banish UpperLeft) >> doIgnore)
```

Other `X` actions can be lifted and sequenced with `doIgnore` similarly.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. I saw `liftX`, but did not manage to make proper use of it with `UpdatePointer`

Comment: @Dmitriusan Feel free to open a fresh question with the details of what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: looks like the code you proposed compiles, but `banish UpperLeft` does not get executed (cursor does not move) when manage hook is triggered. Do you have any idea of what may be wrong, or I should open a new question?

Comment: here are different variants of what I tried https://pastebin.com/CNvM0Hb2

Comment: Nevermind, I found a related discussion of Idea settings to accomplish that another way